# Is it permissible for my cousins (my father's elder brothers' sons) to talk and sit with my mother and aunties?

Tags: halal-haram, family, mahram

I have a bit confusion about something regarding my family!

My father's elder brothers have children, and those children are living in my home with my mom and aunties.

My question: Are those cousins of mine mahram to my mom and aunties allowed to talk to randomly? And even sit with them as they're married women?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on their age. If they are in their early teens they are most likely non-mahram to your mother and your maternal aunties since most boys by around this age grow sexual awareness, and therefore they should observe most if not all rules concerning mahram-non-mahram relations. But they are mahram to their maternal and paternal aunties, that is the sisters of their parents, but not to their aunts-in-law. This aya of the Holy Quran enumerates the mahrams of a women.

> And say to the believing women, that they lower their gaze cast down
>   their eyes and guard their chastity, and do not reveal their adornment
>   except that which is outward (face and hands); and let them draw their
>   veils over their neck, and not reveal their adornment except to their
>   husbands, or their fathers, or their husbands' fathers, or their sons,
>   or their husbands' sons, or their brothers, or their brothers' sons,
>   or their sisters' sons, or their women, or what their right hands own,
>   or such male attendants having no sexual desire, or children who have
>   not yet attained knowledge of women's private parts; nor let them
>   stamp their feet, so that their hidden ornament is known. And, O
>   believers turn to Allah all together, in order that you prosper.
>   ([24:31](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.qaribullah/24:31))